# tabs color changing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I was just wondering about tabs that change color when you are on the selected fragment
For example:
like facebook app tabs, when you are on home page the icon color changes to blue.
Is this a tool or library used, or just i have to explicitly change all colors when fragment change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out bottom navigation view (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView)  by android and use a color selector like

background_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/blue" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

and use this as

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/background_color.xml"
```

in your bottom navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly how any given app does that, but chances are good they are using a [**Color State List**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource) resource or a [**State List Drawable**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable) resource. Such a resource allows you to define different values for different "states" all within a single file. Then you can apply this resource to your tabs (or checkbox or anything else) and it will automatically update accordingly.